# how to insert the sql server database records into the array in c

Tags: c, sql-server, arrays

i am want to perform the kmeans clustering on database in c. For that i need to place the whole database in multidimensional array.

i have created connection in the following way

```
    mySQLConnection = gcnew SqlConnection("Data Source=komal-pc;Initial Catalog=data;Integrated Security=True");
    mySQL = gcnew SqlCommand ("select *  from datatb", mySQLConnection);
    mySQLConnection->Open (); // Open up the connection
    myReader = mySQL->ExecuteReader ();
```

This is the code I have tried so far:

```
c.while(myReader->Read()) {/* for(j=0;j<2;j++) {*/ array[i][0]= Convert::ToInt16 (myReader["id"]); array[i][1]= Convert::ToInt16 (myReader["age"]); } printf("%d", array[i][0]);    printf("%d\n", array[i][1])
```

i m able to read the whole data.
please tell me how to place that data into array

Comment: What language is this for?  Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: this is done using visual c                        for(i=0;i<400;i++)                                while(myReader->Read())
{                                       array[i][0]= Convert::ToInt16 (myReader["id"]);       array[i][1]= Convert::ToInt16 (myReader["age"]);
 }
printf("%d", array[i][0]);     printf("%d\n", array[i][1]);                                                               but with this only last value is present in array

Comment: In the future please put the code in your question, not in the comments here.  i have added it for you this time, but you need to format it to make it readable.  Thanks!